# name 'grinder' is not defined when using Grinder

Tags: python, jython, grinder

Grinder is new for me and I am trying to figure out how to get rid of this error:

my test.py script:

```
import string
import random
from java.lang import String
from java.net import URLEncoder
from net.grinder.plugin.http import HTTPRequest
from net.grinder.common import GrinderException

log = grinder.logger.info
stat = grinder.statistics.forLastTest

SERVER = "http://www.google.com"
URI = "/"

class TestRunner:
        def __call__(self):
                requestString = "%s%s" % (SERVER, URI)
                request = HTTPRequest()
                result = request.GET(requestString)
                if string.find(result.getText(), "SUCCESS") < 1:
                        stat.setSuccess(0)
```

I run

```
java net.grinder.Console
java net.grinder.Grinder
```

in my localhost.
after starting the test, this message keeps popping up:

```
aborting process - Jython exception, <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'grinder' is not defined [initialising test script]
net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'grinder' is not defined
    log = grinder.logger.info
    File "./test.py", line 8, in <module>
```

It looks like I have to include some Grinder module for this "grinder.logger.info" but I just have no clue of what I should import... ...

Any hint?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you imported items from grinder, not grinder itself, try

```
import grinder.logger.info
import grinder.statistics.forLastTest
```

it might also be `net.grinder.logger.info` and `net.grinder.statistics.forLastTest` if this is the case then your code will need changing to go with the change from grinder to net.grinder

Comment: thx for your reply. for the 'info', I use: 'from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder' then use 'log = grinder.logger.info'. Now I can log :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported grinder.

```
from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
```

and now try again.